# Local function variables initialization takes processing time?

Tags: c, variables, time, initialization, local

Local function variables initialization takes processing time? e.g.:

```
void foo ( void ) {
    char *str = "hello";
    int num = 3;
}
```

Or, like global variables, their value is assigned already in the read-only section of the binary?

In other words: Would it be time-consuming to invoke a function that has many local variables, comparing to a function that has none?

***Edit:***
I see many people here are angry because that it seems that I'm trying to optimize my code in a very picky/bad way, which shouldn't be considered. I'm aware of this. I asked this question only to understand how things behave and function, not for optimization reasons. Thank you.
BTW, perhaps my codes sits on a low-power MCU? Consider other options, PC isn't the only one.

Comment: Assigning a variable probably takes between 1 and 4 instructions.  On a 1 Ghz processor this is only going to be about 1-4 nanoseconds.

Comment: How many local variables you will define? 3 millions of them? You will run out of stack space before you'll notice a considerable time delay. Don't focus on micro-optimization.

Comment: I get mad whenever I see stuff like this. Obviously it takes time. You have to assign a variable and set all characters in a string. there is nothing quantitative about this question. Learn to use a profiler, it's the only way to see if you should care about that kind of overhead or not, and it depends on the whole specific program. What were you looking for in an answer exactly?

Comment: Of course doing something is going to cost more then doing nothing.  Perhaps a more specific application of your question will yield better answers to your question.

Comment: @Chris: It does not have to set all the characters of the string. The string can be stored in the binary, it just needs to set str to point to it. If it were `char str[] = "hello";`, the string would have to be created at runtime, but the way it is in the above code, only the pointer has to be set.

Comment: Anytime you ask a question here about how something performs you will get comments about micro-optimization.  Ignore them, it's never wrong to know relative performance of various bits of your code

Comment: @Derek Litz: Does it apply to global variables too? I don't recall that...

Comment: @Dor Even if you using global variables versus local variables.  Globals may stay in memory longer but they may not depending on the code you are analyzing.  If you completely fill the memory with global variables it will be paged out of main memory the same as with local variables.  In this case there is virtually no difference global versus local.  Concerning multiple function calls I'm pretty sure they don't need to be paged in again every function call, unless they were paged out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a lot of time, but yes. it takes time.

In this example the text "hello" would already live somewhere as a constant value,
but `str` would have to be set to point to it at runtime.

and the value 3 would have to be stored in `num`

Comment: Where is this "somewhere"? The read-only section of the binary?

Comment: @Dor: in MSVC it will be in a read-only section of the binary, I don't know about other compilers.

Comment: Compile to assembly (e.g. gcc -S) and see for yourself.

Comment: @Nikolai: 10X, but I'm not yet smart enough to understand x86 ASM or a binary file format.

Answer (score 0):

If you're feeling adventurous, try dissasembling your executable with `objdump` with and without extra variables. You'll see that there are extra instructions inserted by the compiler (either setting a register or doing a load operation) when you create more local variables in your function. Every instruction takes nonzero time...